# Add line break to text area output after a certain number of characters in a form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a CV generator as a practice project, with a form to fill in your CV details on one half of the screen, and with the output that is filled in on the other half of the screen.

Now i have a section for previous jobs that includes a text area to describe the job, my problem is that i want the output to have a line break automatically after a certain amount of characters, what happens now is that it just keeps going to the right in one line no matter how many characters is inputed to the text area. It is the outputted text i want to have a line break not the text inside the text area field.

I have tried to find the solution but i cant find anything applicable probably because i do not know the correct terms to find the solution.

Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Html code below

```html
<div class="kompetanse">
   <textarea rows="5" id="beskrivelse" placeholder="Beskrivelse" value=''></textarea>
</div>
```

css

```css
    .input-fields .input,
    .kompetanse textarea {
       margin: 10px 0;
       background: transparent;
       border: 0;
       font-family: inherit;
       padding: 10px;
       color: #fff;
       font-size: 18px;
     }

    .kompetanse textarea {
      width: 88%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      margin-left: 6%;
    }
```

Comment: Please add what you have achieved/worked so far in terms of code in your question

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti I added the css code related to the text area and the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is that you should look after the width and border values assigned in .kompetanse textarea class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i tried to set the with of the area to 100% now it works if i press enter for a new line in the text area, but if i keep the same sentence long without pressing enter for a new line in the text area the same issue appears.

Comment: the next thing that comes to my mind is that you could make use of iframe to display the output window using jquery which you can easily find out about from google.

Comment: Yes, but you was right about this, i had to add the max width in more than one place in order for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, breakAt; //for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
breakAt = function(){
  const a = [...arguments], s = a.shift().split('');
  for(let v of a){
    s.splice(v, 0, '\r');
  }
  return s.join('');
}
// library above magic below
const ta = I('ta');
ta.value = breakAt(ta.value, 5, 8, 10, -6);
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```html
<textarea id='ta'>Here is some test text to break!</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me. It is the outputted text i want to have a line break not the text inside the text area field. I updated my question to clarify this.